# How to do this in one line using PHP

Tags: php

I have the following structure:

```
$par4 = json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->$par3;
$par5 = $par4[0]->attributes->attribute[1]->value;
```

where par1, par2 and par3 are strings. How do I chain the par4 and par5 on one line.

This does not work because of the array / object nesting I guess:

```
json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->$par3[0]->attributes->attribute[1]->value;
```

Here's the error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$o
```

Comment: the structure of the $source_code would be helpful

Comment: Can you show us what $source_code looks like?

Comment: Yes: http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/search.json?flags=&source=ripe&query-string=8.8.8.8

Comment: `Proxy pass is only valid from within the RIPE NCC Network`

Comment: http://codepad.org/8y2JQGEs - to see structure of source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
$par5 = current(json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->$par3)->attributes->attribute[1]->value;
```

This works if you are always need in the first (0th) value of the array.

You can also create a function that returns the nth-value:

```
function third_value($arr) { return $arr[2]; }
$par5 = third_value(json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->$par3)->attributes->attribute[1]->value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you really need but try  using {} to highlight what you need

```
{json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->$par3}[0] // I think this is right
json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->${par3[0]}
json_decode($source_code)->$par1->$par2->{$par3[0]}
```